# Adobe AIR application: Installation shortcut

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air

How do I get the Adobe AIR installer that I exported from Flash Builder 4.5 install shortcut to the application on the "all users" desktop on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force it, the user must select it during installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The AIR installer prompts you with two options (1) to have a shortcut on the desktop and (2) to run the air app after installation.

Checking the first option pastes the shortcut only on the desktop of the user who installed it. Is there a way to have that on the "all users" desktop?

Comment: Oh sorry, I had not seen the "all" part. I don't think the installer can let you do that. However, you could prompt the user and copy the shortcut in the corresponding all users folder for the OS when the application starts for the first time. You can check that site for folder locations on Windows http://www.lancelhoff.com/accessing-windows-vista-documents-and-setting-folder/